# Get the value of select list in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I created a blade with the following dropdown

```
  <?php
                 $Years = App\InvoiceHeader::pluck('year')
                                           ->all() ;
               ?>
               {{ Form::select('Year', $Years, null) }}
```

I want to use the selected year in another PHP tag in the same blade. How can I get the selected value

Comment: If you want to get the selected value before submitting the form, then you need to use javascript.

Comment: Thus I will not be able to use another php script where the selected value be used in the where clause? If I have to use javascript, I have no javascript experience, how do I do this then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP only runs on server side, this means that you can't manipulate it after the content of the page are sent to the client (browser). So you can't get the value of the input and use for another thing with PHP without send the data to the server and reload the page with the new information. But it isn't a good thing to do and provides a poor user experience.

For manipulate the page on the browser without need to reload we have JavaScript.

In your case you need to add an onchange event on select:

```
{{ Form::select('Year', $Years, null, ['onchange' => 'yearChanged(event)']) }}
```

Then you create the Javascript function:

```
<script>
    function yearChanged(e) {
        //Do anything you want
    }
</script>
```

To get the value of the select inside this function you can use e.target.value